# Reset Dom element to initial state (jquery/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i am trying to add a couple of `css` classes *(red and shrink)* on `mouseover` and `mouseout`. I have successfully done that but once I move my mouse out of the container or area of focus, the `shrink` class still remains.

How can I reset all classes back to the original state?

Here is the code i have so far:

```
var lis = $('.list');

lis.on('mouseover mouseout', changeColor);

function changeColor (e) {
 $el = e.currentTarget;
 if( e.type == 'mouseover') {
    $el.classList.add('red');
    $el.classList.remove('shrink');
 } else if (e.type == 'mouseout'){
    $el.classList.remove('red');
  $el.classList.add('shrink');
 } 
 else {
    $el.classList.remove('red');
    $el.classList.remove('shrink');
 }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: As you're using jquery for the event listener, it seems like it would make more sense to use jquery in the function too..

Comment: The issue still persist even i used jquery.

Comment: What do you expect? you add `shrink` class on mouse out, and you expect it remove all class on mouse out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactored the code using pure jQuery. works as expected.

```
    var lis = $('.list');
    lis.hover(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('red')
        .siblings(lis).toggleClass('shrink');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```js
var lis = $('.list');

lis.on('mouseover mouseout', changeColor);

function changeColor (e) {
 $el = e.currentTarget;
 if( e.type == 'mouseover') {
    $el.classList.add('red');
    $el.classList.remove('shrink');
 } else if (e.type == 'mouseout'){
    $el.classList="list";
 } 

}
```

```css
.list
{ 
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:green;
}

.red
{
    background : red;
}

.shrink
{
    background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list"></div>
```